# How to use setLineDash on a curve in an equidistant way?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to draw a dashed line on a sine wave. I have an array of x and y values which represent the entire sine wave. I have drawn the sine wave using moveTo and lineTo methods.

I am aware of the setLineDash(). But, I want to ensure that the dashed lines are equidistant from each other irrespective of the x and y values. If I use the setLineDash() method between 2 points which are close to each other, I will land up with a solid line.

Comment: Should I consider first drawing the sine wave with the provided values and then copy it to an offscreen canvas and do something with it?

Answer (score 0):

The spaces between each dash will be even, as long as you wait until after your last `lineTo()` call to stroke the path.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width / 8; x+=.1) {
  const y = (Math.sin(x) * 60) + (canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(x * 8, y);
}

ctx.setLineDash([4, 4]);
ctx.stroke();
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```